# For the absolute beginner, how to check out a PayPal business account using Sandbox

Tags: paypal

I've been trying check that the PayPal business account for a website actually works correctly. From what I've read, one has to use the Sandbox to do this.

What steps have to be taken to do this? The PayPal documentation is, I find, difficult to follow. So I'm really at square 1. Could anyone give instructions on how to do this check, in detail please

Answer (score 0):

Here are some quickstart guides I put together that should guide you through getting started with the sandbox environment: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/quickstart/.

Comment: Thank you for your post. As the website is Joomla-based, I guess that PHP would be the language to select for in your guide. Could you please confirm?

Comment: Yes, PHP will be the best for an integration into Joomla